# StringTemplate: how to detect, if variable in tempate is not explicitly set?

Tags: java, string, stringtemplate

I am using StringTemplate to auto-generate configuration files and it's an error, if user haven't defined some of the variables.

StringTemplate will replace undefined variables (I mean $var$) with empty string and error will remain undetected. E.g.:

```
some_property=$some_property$
```

is rendered into:

```
some_property=
```

How to force StringTemplate to raise exception, if variable in template is not explicitly defined using

```
StringTemplate.setAttribute(key, value)
```

?

Comment: It looks like you are using StringTemplate <=3. Is migrating to StringTemplate 4 an option for you?

Comment: Sure, why not. It's for internal use.

Answer (score 1):

With StringTemplate 4 the error listener is informed about an undefined attribute. With a custom error-listener you can handle this as required. For example:

```
    ST tmp = new ST("Hello <name>!");

    tmp.write(new NoIndentWriter(new StringWriter()), new STErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void runTimeError(STMessage msg) {
            if(msg.error == ErrorType.NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE)
              System.out.println("Attribute not defined: "+ msg.arg);
        }

        @Override public void compileTimeError(STMessage msg) { }
        @Override public void IOError(STMessage msg) { }
        @Override public void internalError(STMessage msg) { }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It's too much reworking to migrate to 4.0.8 for now, but I'll invest in it in future. For sure)